# Use getch in while (1) python

Tags: python, getch

I would like to use `char=getch.getch()` in a loop (`while(1)`). 
The problem when I use this like that it block my loop:

```
import getch

while(1):
         char=getch.getch()
         a=read_data()
         if (char=='a'): c=....
         if (char=='b'): c=....
```

If I don't put anything, my loop is blocked... How can I solve this for getting event from my keyboard?

**EDIT** : At the top is an example of what I want to do but if you are interested, my real script is here. I am actually working on an analyser spectrum and I want to scan by pressing some keys:

```
from pylab import *
from rtlsdr import *
from bluetooth import *

import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import getch

sdr=RtlSdr()

#configure device
sdr.center_freq=double(sys.argv[1]) # centrale frequency
sdr.gain=double(sys.argv[2]) #gain
sdr.sample_rate=double(sys.argv[3]) # sample rate

#configure PSD
NFFT=int(sys.argv[4]) # nb points

# Bluetooth connexion
server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)
port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]
uuid="94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
client_sock, client_info=server_sock.accept()

while (1):

    samples=sdr.read_samples(256*1024)
        result=psd(samples,NFFT,Fs=sdr.sample_rate/1e6,Fc=sdr.center_freq*1e6/1e6)

        tab_freq=(result[1]/1e6)
        value_freq=str(tab_freq)[1:-1]
        value_list=[format(float(v), ".5f") for v in value_freq.split()]
        value_freq2= "\n".join(value_list)

        tab_pxx=result[0]
        value_pxx=str(tab_pxx)[1:-1]
        value_list2=[format(float(v), ".7f") for v in value_pxx.split()]
        value_pxx2= "\n".join(value_list2)

        client_sock.send(value_freq2+'\n'+'\n'.join(value_pxx2.split()))

        char=getch.getch()

        if (char=='a'):
        sdr.center_freq=sdr.center_freq+0.1e6
        print 'center_freq+'
        if (char=='z'):
        sdr.center_freq=sdr.center_freq-0.1e6
        print 'center_freq-'
```

Comment: Why not use `input()` instead?

Comment: One of the two functions is blocking, which prevents the loop from continuing until user input is received. What are you trying to accomplish? And what does the `read_data()` function do?

Comment: If you want user input, you're going to have to wait for it regardless, I'm afraid.

Comment: yes, it do not work too. I can't read data.

Comment: Can we see the implementation of `read_data`?

Comment: I just edited my post, read_data was juste an example not really a function

Comment: Consider multi-threading?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, you can use [`msvcrt.kbhit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html#console-i-o) to see if there's a keypress waiting without blocking:

```
import msvcrt
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        # Only if there's a keypress waiting do we get it with getch()
        print "Key hit! ({})".format(msvcrt.getch())
    else:
        # Do something else here
        print "Nothing..."
```

On Linux, it's more complicated because there is no `kbhit()` equivalent.

Comment: ok so if i understood, a simple `while(true)` with `if (getch()=='...')` can solve my problem ? (I am on Linux)

Comment: No, because `getch()` is blocking (it will wait for input). Apologies, I've just realised the question I linked to is not for Python. There is a Linux example here (non SO) http://code.activestate.com/recipes/572182-how-to-implement-kbhit-on-linux/