# How to break countdown with keyboard in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard, wait

In the middle of some process I have a pause with countdown (for loop with time.sleep(1) inside). I'd like to be able to break it with keyboard to be able to continue earlier than countdown got finished.
Is it possible with python3 (cross-platform without Linux root access)? Can I get some information about key pressed in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my "cross-platform" very simplified solution.

```
def my_sleep(wait_sec):
    current_platform = platform.system()
    if current_platform == "Windows":
        import msvcrt

    elif current_platform == "Linux":
        import termios
        from select import select

        # save the terminal settings
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        new_term = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        old_term = termios.tcgetattr(fd)

        # switch to normal terminal
        def set_normal_term():
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, old_term)

        # switch to unbuffered terminal
        def set_curses_term():
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, new_term)

        def kbhit():
            dr, dw, de = select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
            return dr != []

        set_curses_term()
        # new terminal setting unbuffered
        new_term[3] = (new_term[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO)
        set_curses_term()

    for sec_left in range(wait_sec, 0, -1):
        if current_platform == 'Windows':
            if msvcrt.kbhit():
                # print(f':: {msvcrt.getch()}')
                break
        elif current_platform == 'Linux':
            if kbhit():
                ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
                # print(f'::  {ch}')
                break
        print(sec_left)
        time.sleep(1)
    
    if current_platform == "Linux":
        set_normal_term()
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add a short description on how/why your code works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Related to this question: [Use getch in while (1) python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147008/use-getch-in-while-1-python)

Solution: use `kbhit()` and `getch()`: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/msvcrt.html#console-i-o

Working example:

```py
import msvcrt
from time import sleep
def a():
    for n in range(10):
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            return msvcrt.getch()
        sleep(1)
```

Note that it has a reaction delay of up to 1 second

Comment: My bad. Sorry. I did not mention I need cross-platform solution. msvcrt works in Windows only AFAK.